# Show that if $f$ is convex, differentiable and $f(0)=0$ then $f(x) \le xf'(x)$

Tags: analysis, derivatives, solution-verification, convex-analysis

Show that if $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is convex, differentiable and such that $f(0)=0$, then
$$f(x) \le xf'(x), \ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$$

My try: if $x=0$, then since by hypothesis $f(0)=0$ and $f$ is differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$ (so $f'(0)$ exists and is finite) it is $f(0)=0=0\cdot f'(0) \implies f(0)=0 \cdot f'(0)$ and so for $x=0$ the inequality holds; I assume then $x \ne 0$.

Let $x>0$: since by hypothesis $f$ is differentiable and $f(0)=0$, for the mean value theorem there exists $c_x \in (0,x)$ such that $f(x)=xf'(c_x)$. By hypothesis $f$ is convex and differentiable, this is true if and only if $f'$ is non decreasing and so $0<c_x<x \implies f'(c_x)<f'(x)$. Since $x>0$, it follows that $f'(c_x)<f'(x) \implies xf'(c_x)<xf'(x)$ as well. So, for $x>0$, it is $f(x)=xf'(c_x)<xf'(x) \implies f(x)<xf'(x)$.

Similarly, if $x<0$ there exists $k_x \in (x,0)$ such that $f(0)-f(x)=(0-x)f'(k_x) \implies f(x)=xf'(k_x)$. For non decreasing of $f'$, it is $x<k_x<0 \implies f'(x)<f'(k_x)$ and, since $x<0$, it follows that $f'(x)<f'(k_x) \implies xf'(k_x)<xf'(x)$ and so the $f(x)=xf'(k_x)<xf'(x) \implies f(x)<xf'(x)$ as well for $x<0$. Hence, considering all the cases, it holds for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

You can refer this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Properties) and find a useful property to characterize the differentiable convex function:

$$f(y)\geqslant f(x)+f'(x)(y-x)$$

By plugging $y=0$, we have
$$0=f(0)\geqslant f(x)-xf'(x)\, \Longrightarrow xf'(x)\geqslant f(x).$$

Comment: Thanks for your alternative approach, I find it easier and useful. However, my question is specifically about my work (solution verification tag). In any case, +1 to your answer.